# C# byte[] to jbytearray without Copying every Element

Tags: c#, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I am passing a byte array from C# to Java.
Currently my C++ Code looks like this:

```
sendDocument(array<byte> ^arr) //Called by C# class
{ ...
    jbyteArray result = javaEnv->NewByteArray(arr->Length);
    jbyte *bytes = javaEnv->GetByteArrayElements(result, 0);
    for(int k = 0; k < arr->Length ; k++)
    {       
        bytes[k] = arr[k];
    }
    ... //Call Java method
}
```

Can i omit the Copying part somehow (or increase the performance differently)?

**Edit:**
I managed to get it done wtih pointer work:

```
jbyteArray result = javaEnv->NewByteArray(arr->Length);
pin_ptr<unsigned char> pUnmanagedArr = &arr[0];
javaEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, arr->Length, (jbyte*)pUnmanagedArr);
```

but how dirty is this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a good approach for copying data. The only thing dirty about it is the type parameter you used with `pin_ptr` isn't textually the same as the type parameter used with `arr`—no real difference, though.

You omitted the code sections that supply deal with `javaEnv` so be sure that the thread that calls `sendDocument` is initialized and uninitialized  with the JVM (i.e. using `AttachCurrentThread` and `DetachCurrentThread`, or `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and `DestroyJavaVM`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've done the attaching and detaching, but i guess it's good to point it out if someone has the same Problem in future.